# Holo theme not applying to dialogs when using holoeverywhere library

Tags: android, android-theme, android-holo-everywhere

I am using ChristopheVersieux's HoloEverywhere library in my Android project.

Everything is fine except for the dialogs. Holo styles are not applying on AlertDialogs and custom dialogs.

Comment: This is a known bug... I need time to work on this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure you are using the right `import`.

**Replace:**

```
import android.app.AlertDialog
```

**with:**

```
import com.WazaBe.HoloEverywhere.app.AlertDialog;
```

Comment: Does this mess up functionality on ICS devices that actually can simply use android.app.AlertDialog? I fear it might...

Comment: @DanielSmith I don't think it should since it has 'android.app.AlertDialog' in it